# Rstudio load namespace failure

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Recently I have been experiencing problems when running my shiny application. I am fairly new to r and shiny and i am currently developing an application using shiny with Rstudio.The error that occurs is as follows.

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'jsonlite', details:
 call: namespaceExport(ns, exports)                                                          error: undefined exports: versionInfo, diagnosticsReport, previewRd, viewer

This is odd because I am not using the jsonlite package. I have updated shiny and I have run several of the shiny app demos and they have caused the same error as the application I have created. it seems that no matter what type of app i attempt to run comes up with a blank main panel. I would be happy to provide further information needed to solve this issue.

Comment: Shiny uses some commands from the jsonlite package. Do you have have a current version installed?

Comment: I have the current version of both shiny and jsonlite installed.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of RStudio installed?

Comment: I do have the most recent version of r studio